# Logout button crash sitecore 8

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I have an upgraded web forms site from sitecore 7.5 to Sitecore 8 and when I click the logout button inside the sitecore CMS I have the following crash:

```
 Could not invoke action method: Logout. Controller name: Authentication. Controller type: Sitecore.Controllers.AuthenticationController
```

And the following is the stack trace for the crash.

```
 [InvalidOperationException: Could not invoke action method: Logout. Controller name: Authentication. Controller type: Sitecore.Controllers.AuthenticationController]
   Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.SitecoreActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +181
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass22.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1e() +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<.cctor>b__0(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Action action) +20
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +20
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   Sitecore.Mvc.Routing.RouteHttpHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +61
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9629708
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

The url for the crash page is http://hostName/api/sitecore/Authentication/Logout?sc_database=master

Comment: Did you follow the upgrade script provided by Sitecore or was it some custom way of upgrading?

Comment: Yes I followed the steps by sitecore

Comment: Which version of Sitecore 8? Does it happen if you log in and immediately log out again?

Answer (score 0):

This sound like a known bug in Sitecore 8, reference number 26370. Ask Sitecore support for a support package that fits your Sitecore version. They gave me one that works for 8.1, but it may be different for 8.0. The bug is there too.